# EntityFramework Core code first two solutions

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two solutions in c#:

One solution is identity server with asp.net core identity integration, which on first run creates identity user tables.

The second solution I have API, and project Data Layer, where I will implement custom tables.

How do I approach this architecture design, to make sure all migrations will know each other and there wont be data issues. In case I have to create additional table for AspNet_Users and link it with other table, I only have option to put it in Identity solution, but what if there are multiple links? How can I achieve proper architecture here?